# Detect the number of times a word shows up in a string - iphone xcode objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, string

iphone xcode objective-c:

I have a string with alot of text..

I want to detect how many times @"hello" is in the string...

I know how to detect if it is or isn't but how do I detect the number of times it appears in the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\bhello\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:someString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Comment: This seemed to work great but when I tried detecting the string @"[a]" it doesn't look for "[a]", it only searches for "a" ... How can I tell it to not ignore the brackets? I thought it would just be "\[a\]" but that didn't work.

Comment: Had to change the option to "NSRegularExpressionIgnoreMetacharacters" Works great now! Thanks!

Comment: yeah regex are somewhat sensitive to special characters ^^ "\\b" are word boundaries.. so the one above specifically looks for whole words only.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUInteger count = 0, length = [yourString length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length); 
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
  range = [yourString rangeOfString: @"hello" options:0 range:range];
  if(range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
    range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
    count++; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRegularExpression *aRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"Hello" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *targetString = @"Hello, Albert! Hello, again!";
NSInteger numberOfMatches = [aRegex numberOfMatchesInString:targetString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [targetString length])];
[aRegex release];
NSLog(@"number of matches: %d", numberOfMatches); // 2
```

You may need to play a little with the regex.